# Creating evenly (spaced but variable width) table cells

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to create a table based navigation bar for an HTML Email.

The markup is ([JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo4tzu2h/)):

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="">Home</a></td>
  <td class="spacer"><div></div></td>
  <td><a href="">Alumni News</a></td>
  <td class="spacer"><div></div></td>
  <td><a href="">Careers</a></td>
  <td class="spacer"><div></div></td>
  <td><a href="">Firm News</a></td>
  <td class="spacer"><div></div></td>
  <td><a href="">Lawyer Recognitions</a></td>
  <td class="spacer"><div></div></td>
  <td><a href="">Who's New</a></td>
</tr>
```

And it's rendering like this:

[image]

The problem is that, while I want the nav links to be variable size, **I want the padding *between* the items (and spacers) to be even**. Using `table-layout: fixed` just makes everything equal width, breaking the `Lawyer Recognitions` link. The real issue is I'm using table cells for the spacers as well, but I can't think of a clever alternative that would work across all email clients.

This is roughly what I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: I don't thinks this can be done with pure css and table layout. Have you tried some jquery/jquery-ui plugin? Their solutions are working for most cases, so you may not have a crossbrowser problem.

Comment: I don't want to use JS in an HTML email, unfortuantely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

Make the anchors `display:block` and add a margin

```css
.navbar {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 15px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
.navbar td {
  padding: 5px 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ff0000;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background: #f09d09;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table class="navbar">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Alumni News</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Careers</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Firm News</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Lawyer Recognitions</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="">Who's New</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo4tzu2h/6/)

Comment: Thanks! This works great — but that's because there aren't any actual spacers. Using this method I don't think there's any way I can have gold, less than full height spacing lines between the links.

Comment: Not sure what your last comment meant.

Comment: Using your method I can't see how I could replicate the original image. You've used a margin to create a white space between the links. I need it to be gold, and to not extend to the full height of the container.

Comment: Sure you can - use a border-right on the `td` and add a little padding to the table - http://jsfiddle.net/Lo4tzu2h/10/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, missed that! Works perfectly. I think I'll have a hard time with last child working across HTML emails, but I can always apply an additional class.

Comment: As an extra pointer you should use `padding-top:  5px; padding-bottom: 5px;` instead of the shorthand.  You should not use margin on the `<a>` it won't render in Outlook.  If you are going to use it capitalise the M `Margin`, don't use shorthand use `Margin-top:` and don't use `rem` use px, em or %.  % is the most stable, px will be converted into pt by Outlook.